# SQL Server Inner Join on same column with two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join

I am thinking about a possibility in doing inner joins with the below 3 tables.

**CategorizedItems**

```
CategoryId | linkid | type 
------------------------------
1              1        a1  
1              2        a1  
1              1        a2
```

**A1_Items**

```
itemid  | Name | A1 Fields
-----------------------------
1          N1
2          N2
```

**A2_items**

```
itemid  | Name | A2 Fields
-----------------------------
1          N3
```

CategorizedItems.linkId can hold A1_items.itemid and A2_items.itemid. Because of that, there are no primary key -  foreign key relationship among them.

I am in the need to get the names of the items under CategoryId 1.

Is there a possibility to do this. I dont have any field representing 'type' in A1_items and A2_Items.

I guess that I can achieve it by doing 2 queries (or)  By doing a  union with the results of 2 separate queries.

In my real time scenario, I have multiple tables connected with these 3 tables. Redoing the joins for all the  other tables, just for the above scenario is costly..

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use left joins and apply a suitable filter to your joins like this:

```
SELECT CategoryId, COALESCE(A1_Items.Name, A2_Items.Name) AS Name
FROM CategorizedItems
LEFT JOIN A1_Items ON A1_Items.itemid = CategorizedItems.linkid AND CategorizedItems.type = 'a1'
LEFT JOIN A2_Items ON A2_Items.itemid = CategorizedItems.linkid AND CategorizedItems.type = 'a2'
```

**<kbd>[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f7965/5)</kbd>**

Comment: Thanks Dan. I will try this and post my results.

Comment: It worked Dan. Thanks a lot. Alzaimar's approach uses one join and one union, Is that approach more optimized compared to 2 joins and a coalesce. I may also use multiple common fields to coalesce in future.

Comment: @Beetles: That's a tough question to answer. The answer depends on what indices you have on the tables and the amount of data in either table. Note that the `COALESCE()` function is a scalar function that runs in O(1) - you could just as well have used `ISNULL()` - it should not affect performance at all. Also note that my approach will not necessarily give the same result as Alzaimar's, since I'm using LEFT JOIN's, which would also return rows from CategorizedItems, that have no match in either Items-table.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:

```
select CategoryID, Name
from CategorizedItems c
     join (select 'a1' as table, ItemId, Name from A1_Items
           union
           select 'a2' as table, ItemId, Name from A2_Items) a
     on c.linkId = a.ItemId and c.type = a.table
```

Comment: Thank you. I implemented your approach for simplicity in coding. Also It uses one join.

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
 SELECT CategoryId, isnull(A1_Items.Name, A2_Items.Name) AS Name FROM CategorizedItems LEFT JOIN A1_Items ON A1_Items.itemid = CategorizedItems.linkid AND CategorizedItems.type = 'a1' LEFT JOIN A2_Items ON A2_Items.itemid = CategorizedItems.linkid AND CategorizedItems.type ='a2'
```

Comment: Thanks Nitu, I guess isnull works the same way as coalesce. Is there any difference in it.

Comment: `ISNULL()` only takes two parameters (an original value and a replacement value in case the original is NULL). `COALESCE()` allows you to specify any number of parameters, and effectively just works as a chain of nested ISNULL's.